# Multiple joins mocks and Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, stub, sequel

I'm trying to mock this statement, but I can't find anything on the internet to help me:

```
  someone_ids = Office.join(:address, id: :address_id)
                      .join(:office_someone, id: :id)
                      .pluck(:someone_id)
```

Here is the spec that I'm using:

```
  expect(Office).to receive(:join)
                .with(:office_someone, { :id => :id })
                .with(:address, { :id => :address_id })
                .and_return([1])
```

Does anybody know how to mock multiple `join`? I'm using `Sequel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previously RSpec had a stub_chain method that allowed you to do something like that easily, however it was removed because it encouraged bad practices, and now you'll have to stub each response manually:

```
office = instance_double(Office)
expect(Office).to receive(:join)
              .with(:address, { :id => :address_id })
              .and_return(office)
expect(office).to receive(:join)
              .with(:office_someone, { :id => :id })
              .and_return(office)
expect(office).to receive(:pluck).with(:someone_id).and_return([1])
```

Which if its a code that you find yourself repeating too much will made you think about refactoring it, which in the end is one of the reasons people do testing: "If its hard to test, it might not be well designed"

Comment: You can still use `receive_message_chain` to stub/mock message chains.

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/message-chains

But it doesn't have the possibility of customising the arguments, so it probably is quite useless in the OPs case.